# How to increase the folder name in a text field and save each time the program runs?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public class CountFolder {
        int count = 0;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            CountFolder test1 = new CountFolder();

            test1.doMethod();

        }

        public void doMethod() {

            count++;
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
```

> I want to call it in the send keys section and save the count. So each time it will create a new folder.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).sendKeys("AutomationTest_count");
```

Comment: I am not sure if anyone is able to understand your question. Do you want to pass incremented number to sendkeys? is it your question?

Comment: Please add some more details to make the question more clear. Examples are always helpful, etc. Read [ask] for more tips.